# Heyoffline in Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js

I am building an Ember CLI app and want to use Heyoffline.js. I have installed this using Bower:

bower.js:

```
"Heyoffline": "~1.1.1"
```

Brocfile:

```
app.import('bower_components/Heyoffline/heyoffline.js');
```

I am then trying to load this using an initialiser, as below. However this does not seem to work - nothing happens when I go offline. There are no errors in the console. Am I loading this incorrectly? Thanks.

```
export default {
    name: 'heyoffline',
    initialize: function() {

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

            new Heyoffline();

        }, false);
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you using phonegap? The `deviceready` event won't trigger in web browsers

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by setting "service" to an instance of HeyOffline in the application, as follows:

```
export default {
    name: 'heyoffline',
     initialize: function(registry, application) {

        ...        

        var heyoffline = HeyOffline.create();
        application.set('service', heyoffline);        
      }
};
```

I also had to create an Ember object for HeyOffline:

```
var HeyOffline = Ember.Object.extend({
  service: null,
  init: function() {
    this.set('service', new Heyoffline());
    this.set('service.options.disableDismiss', true); //this is optional, see http://krawczyk.io/heyoffline.js/
  }
});
```

Comments welcome :)